# image is not displayed in html page?

Tags: html

I am using html. inside a table i have to display a logo. PFB code.

```
<table>
           <tr>
       <td>
<img src="C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop.company.jpg" />
</td> 
       </tr>

</table>
```

but image is not displayed. instead a blank image is displayed as below. [image]

what is wrong with my code? why actual image is not displaying here? Please help me.

Thanks!

Comment: Where is your page running, is it also on a file path?

Comment: The image path is local. Is the html page local too? I suppose not!

Answer (score 1):

Your image path refers to your C:/ disk. Your C:/ disk is not accessible by everyone on the internet (I might hope).

I suggest you read this before you publish your website: http://www.webreference.com/html/tutorial2/3.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Your path no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

image tag take 2 type of value of src attribute

1) relative path
2) server path

your path is not allowed

make folder name "images" in same directory where your file is and put image into it

give src like this `<img src="images\Desktop.company.jpg" />`

Answer (score 0):

If your image name is company.jpg then it should be

```
<img src="C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\company.jpg" />
```

and not

```
<img src="C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop.company.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

write code like below and see your problem solved

```
file:///C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\company.jpg
```